# Bring together arrays for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have mutiple arrays and want to display them in a table with ng-repeat. How can i merge arrays like a
name=[name1,name2] und type=[type1,type2] to a data=[..] so i can ng-repeat data.name and data.type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component, you can an object as per your requirement.
For example:

```
const names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];
const types = ['type1', 'type2', 'type3'];

const data = [];

for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++)  {
    data.push({name: names[i], type: types[i]});
}

console.log(data); // [{name: 'name1', type: 'type1'}, ... and so on]
```

In your view, you can iterate over `data` to render table, for example:

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.type }}</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

```
var firstArray = ['John', 'David', 'Bob'];
var secondArray = ['Mike','Sam','Carol'];
var arrayOfObject = firstArray.map(function (value, index){
   return [value, secondArray[index]]
});
```

o/p: `[ [ 'John', 'Mike' ], [ 'David', 'Sam' ], [ 'Bob', 'Carol' ] ]`